# Groovy Closure explanation

Tags: groovy

I'm familiar with normal groovy closures like these

```
def printSum = {a,b ->
   println a+b
}

printSum(5,7) // 12
```

However, I came across code from SpringWS plugin that I have a hard time understanding:

```
def withEndpointRequest = { url, payload ->
    def writer = new StringWriter()
    def request = new MarkupBuilder(writer)
    payload.delegate = request
    payload.call()
    def webServiceTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate()

    def response = webServiceTemplate.sendToEndpoint(url, writer.toString())
    new XmlSlurper().parseText(response)
}
```

I understand that above is a closure.

It is being used like this:

```
    def namespace = "http://www.myveryimportantcompany.com/hr/schemas"
    def serviceURL = "http://localhost:8080/myapp/services"
    def response = withEndpointRequest(serviceURL) {
        HolidayRequest(xmlns: namespace) {
            Holiday {
                StartDate("2006-07-03")
                EndDate("2006-07-07")
            }
            Employee {
                Number("42")
                FirstName("Russ")
                LastName("Miles")
            }
        }
    }
```

if `serviceURL` is being passed in then where is the payload?

Can someone please explain this snippet in some detail?

Comment: It looks like payload is injected by the plugin with some kind of method interception.

Comment: It looks like the stuff in the braces is the payload (the `HolidayRequest`). Perhaps Groovy has some syntactic sugar that lets you specify function arguments in that way? Try testing it by calling `printSum(5) { 7 }` or something similar to that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the above implementation, `withEndpointRequest` is a closure which takes two parameters.

`withEndpointRequest(String serviceUrl, Closure payload)`.

When you are using `withEndpointRequest` from your client, you are actually doing

```
    def namespace = "http://www.myveryimportantcompany.com/hr/schemas"
    def serviceURL = "http://localhost:8080/myapp/services"
    def payload = {
         HolidayRequest(xmlns: namespace) {
            Holiday {
                StartDate("2006-07-03")
                EndDate("2006-07-07")
            }
            Employee {
                Number("42")
                FirstName("Russ")
                LastName("Miles")
            }
        }
    }
    def response = withEndpointRequest(serviceURL, payload)
```

The above was made groovier by declaring the closure inline with `withEndpointRequest`.
The above can also be written as

```
def response = withEndpointRequest(serviceURL, {
        //payload goes here as an inline closure as the second parameter
        HolidayRequest(xmlns: namespace) {
            Holiday {
                StartDate("2006-07-03")
                EndDate("2006-07-07")
            }
            Employee {
                Number("42")
                FirstName("Russ")
                LastName("Miles")
            }
        }
    })
```

which is less verbose. Finally, it can be streamlined and made more groovier by writing as

```
def response = withEndpointRequest(serviceURL) {
        HolidayRequest(xmlns: namespace) {
            Holiday {
                StartDate("2006-07-03")
                EndDate("2006-07-07")
            }
            Employee {
                Number("42")
                FirstName("Russ")
                LastName("Miles")
            }
        }
    }
```

One point to note here is that the `Closure payload` is the last parameter.

Now, note that the closure (`payload`) is not invoked until `payload.call()` is invoked as mentioned in your question inside SpringWS plugin.

Have a look at [Closures as Method Arguments](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Closures).

I hope I was able to convey what you wanted to understand. :)

Answer (score 0):

The following snipet, posted [here](http://mrhaki.blogspot.fr/2009/11/groovy-goodness-passing-closures-to.html), gives an overview of several options used to pass a closure into a method.

Method with two arguments. Last argument is a closure.

```
def work(input, cl) {
    cl(input)
}
```

Define a closure.

```
def assertJava = {
    it == 'Java'
}
```

Ways to pass the closure to the method

```
work('Java', assertJava)

work 'Java', assertJava  // No parenthesis.

work('Groovy', {
    assert it == 'Groovy'
})  // Anonymous closure as argument.

work('Groovy') {
    assert it == 'Groovy'
}  // Last argument is closure and can be outside parenthesis. 

work('Groovy')
{
     assert it == 'Groovy'
}  // Opening bracket on new line. If we want a code block (e.g. static initializer) instead of closure we must use ; to separate code.


work 'Groovy', {
    assert it == 'Groovy'
}  // Pay attention, no parenthesis, so comma is needed again!


// Does not work:
//
// Comma between argument list needed:
// work 'Groovy' {
//     assert it == 'Groovy'
// }
```